# Open Activity on ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm pretty new in the Android programming world. I'm using the code from [this site](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/) and I want to click on the images to open a new activity. Can anyone help me with this?

This is the xml:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0px"
tools:context=".StreamActivity" />
```

And the first part of the Java code:

```
public class StreamActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stream);

    StreamAdapter adapter = new StreamAdapter(this);
    ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list)).setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.add(new StreamItem(this, R.drawable.photo1, "Option1", "Click to open"));
    adapter.add(new StreamItem(this, R.drawable.photo2, "Option2", "Click to open"));
    adapter.add(new StreamItem(this, R.drawable.photo3, "Option3", "Click to open"));
    adapter.add(new StreamItem(this, R.drawable.photo4, "Option4", "Click to open"));
    adapter.add(new StreamItem(this, R.drawable.photo5, "Option5", "Click to open"));
    adapter.add(new StreamItem(this, R.drawable.photo6, "Option6", "Click to open"));
    adapter.add(new StreamItem(this, R.drawable.photo7, "Option7", "Click to open"));
```

Comment: First of all create an instance of your ListView. as ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list); and then call its onItemClickListener() method

Comment: After adding item in adapter den set it to listview. .not befor adding items to adapter as you are doing here..den onitemclick() get itemposition den pass intent to each position. .if you need code den I can provide

Answer (score 0):

[`ListView.setOnItemClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29). You can have your Activity implement the interface and then call `listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);` inside of `onCreate()`.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // create an Intent to open the next Activity.
    // If you need information from the selected item, use
    StreamItem item = adapter.getItem(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add listener for clicks on your list

```
yourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourTargetClass.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ListView guide if you haven't: [Android developer ListView guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

That example extends ListActivity and implements onListItemClick. In that method, create an Intent and call startActivity.

Here's another example with lots of information and a different way to do the listener: [ListView tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)